# Get Users role in xamarin.android

Tags: rest, azure, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I have made a `xamarin.android` app that uses login authentication with WebAPI and Azure, its working successfully.
Now I want to get the right of the user either he is admin or reader from my database.
Please guide me through.
Here is my login code.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Xamarin_login(string username, string password) {
        var user = db.UserCredentials.Where(x => x.UName == username && x.UIPassword == password).FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null) {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Please Enter valid UserName and Password");
        } else { 
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "Success");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, I guess you may use your own database to store the user Credential and its role.

So if you want to get the user's role, you could use the Linq to search the user in the role.

Firstly, you should have a user role table in your database and this table will be related with the user Credential table or you just store the user role in the Credential table.

If you use EF and you have related with the user role table.

You could use below codes:

```
db.UserRole.Where(x => x.userid(or name according to your design or directly user object) = uerid).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you store the role in the UserCredentials table.

You just find the role property in the user object.

Something like:

```
user.role
```

If you doesn't use EF, you just need to use the sql query to query your database according to the user name or id to get its role.

Besides, if you still don't know how to get it, I suggest you could post more related codes with your db entity model(if you use EF or something else) or post how your sql database table designed.